# Problems with updating XCode 5 with Cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

```
XCode cannot run the selected device. Choose a destination with supported architecture to run on this devide.
```

I've tried changing the Supported architectures and as it is right now

```
arm62 , armv7 , armv7s
```

Updated my XCode from 4.6 I believe to 5.0 and cant run any application now. 
Hope you guys can help me. Thanks

(Found a similar question but with no answer)

Comment: It's `arm64`, not 62.

Comment: What device you are trying to run on ? and what iOS it has ?

Comment: I have never seen the list comma separated, try using "arm64 armv7 armv7s" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue while building some sample app downloaded from internet. Tried lot of things like cleaning project and setting valid architecture etc.. provided in other threads but was not helpful.

But, I found out that the compiler was not set in build options of build settings. Check for "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C"

I changed "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" setting to Default compiler(Apple LLVM 5.0) and it worked for me!

But, you also need to check "architectures" set in build settings.

I hope this helps!!